# Document root element "configuration" , must match DOCTYPE root "null

Tags: log4j, mule, pom.xml

I am using log4j2 for logging.
I am getting the following error during deployment.[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5IsF.jpg)

log4j2.xml file is as follows:
[log4j2.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYysE.jpg)

log4j2.xml was placed under src/main/resources folder.
No jar file was added in pom file since it is part of the mule server. (mule 3.8.1)

Can someone help me with the same.
Thanks.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="file" fileName="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}PCIDirectAPI.log" 
                 filePattern="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}PCIDirectAPI-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) %-5p %c(1):%L - %m%n" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!-- CXF is used heavily by Mule for web services -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.cxf" level="WARN"/>

        <!-- Apache Commons tend to make a lot of noise which can clutter the log-->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>

        <!-- Reduce startup noise -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.beans.factory" level="WARN"/>

        <!-- Mule classes -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.mule" level="INFO"/>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft" level="INFO"/>

        <!-- Reduce DM verbosity -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.jetel" level="WARN"/>
        <AsyncLogger name="Tracking" level="WARN"/>

        <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="file" />
        </AsyncRoot>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Is image showing entire log4j2.xml configuration? I can't see closing tags for Loggers and configuration. Check that.

Comment: Yes. I have the closing tags.

Comment: Do we need to add the DOCTYPE log4j.dtd in the xml file?

Comment: Can you post your log4j2.xml configuration? I will try to check the problem.

Comment: log4j2.xml added

Comment: I am able to deploy application with given log4j2.xml configuration. The error could be related to something else. Check the full error stack trace and see if there is any other error.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you use log4j version 1.x, not version 2.x .

Correct maven dependency for 2.x version is `"org.apache.logging.log4j"/"log4j-slf4j-impl"`, not `"org.slf4j"/"slf4j-log4j12"`.

Comment: Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).